# Why would my battery widget stop updating overnight?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a widget in the market. I've noticed, and have been receiving reports from users, that when the phone is left charging overnight, my battery widget (shows battery charge status, capacity) no longer updates.

The process is still running, though. Is this something I'm doing wrong? I can't duplicate it in the emulator.

And heck, I've got the source up on [github](http://github.com/tjsimmons/super-android-battery) if anyone wants to take a look at it.

Thanks!

Comment: When you're saying you can't duplicate in the emulator... do you mean that you don't know how to duplicate the charging/discharging events, or that you have done that already and can't duplicate the bug?

Comment: I can't duplicate the bug. I've got the emulator running right now at 100% and charging, I've killed the process (and it automatically restarts), and it works just fine.

Comment: Did you try messing around with the power options for the emulator to simulate various scenarios? (See: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#power )

Comment: Yeah, I have. It doesn't happen in the emulator, so I don't know if it's only if the service is running for a certain amount of time or what. I've had the emulator running for about two hours at this point, and I'll check on it later in the day to see.

Comment: Did you get any feedback regarding devices and OS versions? Wondering if it's anything specific to something like that.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be across all devices/OS versions, at least from what I've heard. I don't know if it's affecting everyone, as I've only heard from a handful of people, but it's affecting me. And the people I've heard from have all been on different devices and versions.